# Type of nonzero integers in Idris?

Tags: types, idris

I have a function that returns an integer that should be nonzero, and would like to guarantee that through its return type. How do you express the type of nonzero integers in Idris?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your function there are different ways. If you use `Nat` as return type, you could read about [Theorem Proving in the Idris Tutorial](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/theorems.html). An example would be `inc` that increases a `Nat` and a proof `incNotZ`, that for every `n : Nat`, `Not (inc n = Z)`:

```
inc : Nat -> Nat
inc n = S n

incNotZ : (n : Nat) -> Not (Z = inc n)
incNotZ n p = replace {P = incNotZTy} p ()
  where
    incNotZTy : Nat -> Type
    incNotZTy Z = ()
    incNotZTy (S k) = Void
```

Sometimes you can generate a proof alongside the result, f.e.:

```
data NotZero : Nat -> Type where
  MkNotZero : (n : Nat) -> NotZero (S n)

inc : (n : Nat) -> NotZero (S n)
inc n = MkNotZero n

rev : NotZero n -> Not (n = 0)
rev (MkNotZero n) = SIsNotZ -- from Prelude.Nat
```

Here `NotZero n` is a proof that `n` is not zero, as `n` can only be constructed via `(S n)`. And indeed one can transform any `NotZero n` to `Not (n = 0)` with `rev`.

If your proof type fits the function this is often the better option. Because of both `inc` and `NotZero` having `(n : Nat) -> … (S n)` you get the proof for free. On the other hand, if you want to proof something about a function, what property it holds, like the commutativity or symmetry of `plus`, the first approach is needed.

---

If you are using `Int` as return type, this isn't usually useful, because `Int` can overflow and Idris can't argue about `Int` (or `Integer` or `Float` or …):

```
*main> 10000000000000000000 * (the Int 5)
-5340232221128654848 : Int
```

So the usual approach would be to construct a proof at runtime to see if the non-zeroness holds:

```
inc' : Int -> Int
inc' i = abs i + 1

incNotZ' : (i : Int) -> Either (So (inc' i == 0)) (So (not (inc' i == 0)))
incNotZ' i = choose (inc' i == 0)
```

Then when you call incNotZ' you can match on the result to get a proof on the right or handle the error case on the left.

If you are using for example non-overflowing `Integer` and are really, really sure that your function will never return a 0, you can force the compiler to believe you:

```
inc' : Integer -> Integer
inc' i = abs i + 1

incNotZ' : (i : Integer) -> Not (0 = inc' i)
incNotZ' i = believe_me
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really helpful to me. I must admit that I'm a complete Idris novice (working through TDD right now), and my ideas regarding what types can do for you and how you use them seem to have been a bit naive. My initial belief was that you should encode the semantics of a function in its type signature (as precise as needed). For example, having the return type of a function be `Fin 5` instead of `Nat`, to formalize that the natural number returned is < 5. Separating such an assumption into a separate proof function, as in your example, seems to be the better approach.

Comment: Hey, I thought your question was more about `Int` and `Integer` and not about proofs. So I added another option to mirror the `Fin 5` example. If you want more clarification or have a concrete function in mind, feel free to ask about it. :-)

Comment: The concrete function I have in mind should do nothing but return a nonzero `Int` (the implementation is just the constant function `1`), and I would like to formally specify this constraint in code (I know this sounds silly). As an approximation, I tried defining a data type like your `NotZero` for the simpler case of a return type of `Integer` instead of `Int`, but somehow couldn't figure that out either. But, I also realized that having such a data type probably doesn't actually solve my problem unless there's a way to tell Idris to recognize `NotZero` as a subtype of `Integer`.

Comment: Afaik, there doesn't seem to be a way to define subtypes at all in Idris, so it seems that defining a separate proof like your `incNotZ'`is the way to go.